# Django-twoscoops-project (skeleton) on Heroku via Gunicorn. How to set Procfile?

Tags: django, heroku, gunicorn, procfile

I'm trying to run the [twoscoopsofdjango skeleton](https://github.com/twoscoops/django-twoscoops-project) on Heroku via Gunicorn.

Here is the file tree from the root of the project (left out a few unimportant folders for readability):

```
.
├── LICENSE.txt
├── my_project
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── my_project
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── settings
│   │   │   ├── base.py
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── local.py
│   │   │   ├── production.py
│   │   │   └── test.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── wsgi.py
│   └── templates
│       ├── 404.html
│       ├── 500.html
│       └── base.html
├── README.rst
├── requirements
│   ├── base.txt
│   ├── local.txt
│   ├── production.txt
│   └── test.txt
└── requirements.txt
```

Now I need to run Gunicorn as if it was run from the `my_project` folder in the following shortened tree:

```
.
├── LICENSE.txt
├── my_project
│   ├── manage.py
```

However, I need to give the command from the **project root** because a Heroku `Procfile` is only picked up on the lowest level of the project root.

So inside a shell locally I would just `cd my_project` and then run `gunicorn my_project.wsgi --settings=my_project.settings.production`. But I don't know how to do this from a `Procfile`.

And just for your information `gunicorn --pythonpath=my_project my_project.wsgi --settings=my_project.settings.production` does not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I had to run `heroku ps:scale web=1` to get it working properly. This is strange because I am 100% sure I started other Heroku projects before and I didn't have to run that command in order to see my application working in http://my_project.herokuapp.com.

My Procfile looked like this when it ran successfully:

`web: cd my_project; gunicorn my_project.wsgi --settings=my_project.settings.production`

### Edit

I previously ran gunicorn with the `-w 1` option:

`web: cd my_project; gunicorn my_project.wsgi -w 1 --settings=my_project.settings.production`

That probably activated a dyno.